http header Content-Disposition missing in response for file serving in libwebsockets api
I am using libwebsockets library for https server implementation.
Here is the code to serve a file via HTTPS, But I receive HTTPS response without header variable
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=logs.zip

and received content of the file in response body !
Am I missing anything here? I hope adding Content-Disposition will enable browser client to download file.
Here is my mount:
struct lws_http_mount mount = {
    /* .mount_next */               NULL,               /* linked-list "next" */
    /* .mountpoint */               "/",                /* mountpoint URL */
    /* .origin */                   "var/www/",     /* serve from dir */
    /* .def */                      NULL,               /* default filename */
    /* .protocol */                 NULL,
    /* .cgienv */                   NULL,
    /* .extra_mimetypes */          "application/zip", //NULL,
    /* .interpret */                NULL,
    /* .cgi_timeout */              0,
    /* .cache_max_age */            0,
    /* .auth_mask */                0,
    /* .cache_reusable */           0,
    /* .cache_revalidate */         0,
    /* .cache_intermediaries */     0,
    /* .origin_protocol */          LWSMPRO_FILE,       /* files in a dir */
    /* .mountpoint_len */           1,                  /* char count */
    /* .basic_auth_login_file */    NULL,
};


    if (lws_serve_http_file(wsi, "/tmp/log.zip", "application/zip", NULL, 0) < 0) {
        lwsl_err("Failed to serve file: %s\n", "/tmp/log.zp");
        lws_return_http_status(wsi, HTTP_STATUS_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, NULL);
        return ;
    }

And here is the response headers

Thanks for the support

Yes.
The library doesn't know 1) that you want that header nor 2) what content you want in the header. It provides a mechanism for specifying this (other_headers) but you are not sending any.
My C is a little rusty (no pun intended)....
char disphdr[80]="Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=logs.zip";
if (lws_serve_http_file(wsi
   , "/tmp/log.zip", "application/zip"
   , disphdr, strlen(disphdr)) < 0) {


Thanks @symcbean  with the above code I see error:
Parse Error: There seems to be an invalid character in response header key or value
in postman

Content-Disposition seems okay still getting Parsing error. Here is the captured msg logs:
[3148] N: lws_ssl_capable_write: len 148
[3149] N:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK..content-type: application/zip..content-length:27419..cache-control: no-store..Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=logs.zip..
lwsi_set_state: lwsi_set_state 0x20000119 -> 0x20000015
_lws_change_pollfd: fd 12 events 1 -> 5

This worked.
char disphdr[80] = "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="logs.zip"\r\n";
